# What order does a C# dataset get used?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Assume this piece of code:

```
//Query the Reports table to find the record associated with the selected report
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
                                 WHERE CLIENT_ID =  '" + txtClientID.Text + "'", con))
   {
       con.Open();
       using (SqlDataReader DT1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           // If the SQL returns any records, process the info
           if (DT1.HasRows)
              {
                  while (DT1.Read())
                  {
                      try
                          {
                             int TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTask.SelectedValue);
                             Label2.Text = (DT1["CUST_NM"].ToString());
```

My question is, if

```
"SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
    WHERE CLIENT_ID =  '" + txtClientID.Text + "'"
```

returns a recordset with 25 records, is Label2.Text going to be filled with data from the first record returned by the SQL, or the last record returned?

Comment: You should ask yourself what happens when someone types in `'; Drop table VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation; --` in to `txtClientID`

Comment: The Text property is set to the current value from the current record inside the loop. Because at every loop you substitute the previous content you end the loop with the value from the last record

Comment: I would think it would have been easier and quicker to test this on your own instead of asking on SO, no?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Probably not much, since vw_mos_dpl_accountvalidation is a view.  Although, I guess they could keep trying stuff after that didn't work, but the whole thing in on an Intranet and our manager decided to change our shop from Access to C# without offering us any training, so we're learning as we go.

Answer (score 4):

Collections in SQL are unordered, unless you explicitly order them.  Since the data is unordered the label will effectively have a random element from the collection, so whether it's the first or the last isn't really relevant.

That said, since you're overwiting the value for each item in the results, it will have the last item in the results, not the first, when the whole operation completes, even though you have no idea what the last item will be without an `order by` call.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be filled with data from every record, i.e. replaced within each loop iteration, but at the end, it will have the data from the last record.

It doesn't really make sense to do it the way you're doing it.  What would make more sense is if you either a.) had a grid control or some other kind of composite control where you wanted each row of the grid to contain a value from your query or b.) limited your query to return only one result and used that result to populate your single label.

Additionally, I feel obligated to point out something **very important** that is wrong with your query as you currently have it.  Your query is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack, as Scott Chamberlain alluded to in his comment.  Instead of doing this:

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
                                 WHERE CLIENT_ID =  '" + txtClientID.Text + "'", con)
```

You should do this:

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation WHERE CLIENT_ID = @ID", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", txtClientID.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be set for each row in the data set. So at the end, it will have the value of the last row.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add ***order by*** into query and then take the *1st item*?
There's no need to *fetch all the records* in order to get the last one only.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  @"  select CUST_NM 
        from VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
       where CLIENT_ID = @PRM_CLIENT_ID
    order by CUST_NM -- if you want to reverse add 'desc'", 
  con)) {

  con.Open();

  // Do not hardcode - use parameters 
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@PRM_CLIENT_ID, txtClientID.Text);

  using (SqlDataReader DT1 = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    // DT1.HasRows redundant - DT1.Read() returns true if record is read
    if (DT1.Read()) {
      int TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTask.SelectedValue);
      Label2.Text = (DT1["CUST_NM"].ToString()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution uses an "@"  prior to the "Select" in the SQL string, while roryap's does not.  Can you explain which one is correct, and why?

Comment: @JohnnyBones the "@" before the select is a C# thing. It changes the way strings are handled, the way your and roryap's code is would not compile due to a new line being inside the string, having the @ makes the new line part of the string and it keeps reading till it finds the next `"`